# Efetuar upload de arquivo via FTP TLS

Tags: c#

Estou tentando efetuar upload de arquivos via FTP (TLS), porém não tenho sucesso pois sempre retorna um erro no momento em que o meu código executa o "Connect()". Já tentei utilizar as classes FtpWebRequest , FtpClient, Tamir.SharpSsh e o SftpClient. Qualquer um deles durante a instrução "Connect()" recebo uma mensagem de falha na conexão, segue detalhe:

a) Conectar com classes para SFTP
Exemplo:

```
    private void UploadSFTPFile(string host, string username, string 
           password, string sourcefile, string destinationpath, string port)
    {
        int port2 = Convert.ToInt32(port);

        try
        {
            using (SftpClient client = new SftpClient(host, port2, username, password))
            {
                client.Connect();  //o erro ocorre aqui!!
                client.ChangeDirectory(destinationpath);

                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sourcefile, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        client.BufferSize = 4 * 1024;
                        client.UploadFile(fs, Path.GetFileName(sourcefile));
                        Global.retorno = "Envio via SFTP " + host + " efetuado com sucesso.";
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Global.retorno = "Erro no envio do arquivo via SFTP (1)" + host + ". Detalhe: " + ex;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Global.retorno = "Erro na conexão via SFTP (2)" + host + ". Detalhe: " + ex;
        }
    }
```

Mensagem de erro:
 "Uma tentativa de conexão falhou porque o componente conectado não respondeu corretamente após um período de tempo ou a conexão estabelecida falhou porque o host conectado não respondeu..."

IMPORTANTE:
Tentei também utilizar a classe/biblioteca "WinSCP", para este caso tive a seguinte mensagem de retorno:
"Connection failed. Authentication failed. Connection failed. TLS required".

O mais estranho é que com o FileZila eu conecto sem problemas informando o host, userName e passaword. Não preciso informar chave ou certificado e conecto normalmente. Assim, não tenho clareza do que esta ocorrendo.

Devo ou não utilizar uma chave/certificado para conectar? Mesmo o Filizila não precisando desta...

Obs.Framework 4.5.2

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, porém não se trata de um FTP simples, ele pede uma chave pública (TLS) a qual eu não tinha conhecimento, há pouco encontrei a solução. Basicamente utilizei o WinSCP (https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library). O que acredito ser relevante para quem passar pelo mesmo problema (pois sofri para descobrir), é que dentro do Filezila é possível descobrir a chave pública e utiliza-la no código conforme abaixo (tkey):

```
    private void UploadFTPTLSFile(string host, string username, string password, string sourcefile, string destinationpath, string port, string tkey)
    {
        //https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library

        int port2 = Convert.ToInt32(port);
        destinationpath = destinationpath + "\\" + arquivoUpFtpChk;

        try
        {
            SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
            {
                Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
                HostName = host,
                UserName = username,
                Password = password,
                FtpSecure = FtpSecure.Implicit,
                TlsHostCertificateFingerprint = tkey //aqui vai a chave pública que pode ser descoberta a qual o Filezila utiliza...
            };

            using (WinSCP.Session session = new WinSCP.Session())
            {
                // Connect
                session.Open(sessionOptions);

                // Upload files
                TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
                transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

                TransferOperationResult transferResult;
                transferResult =
                    session.PutFiles(sourcefile, destinationpath, false, transferOptions);

                // Throw on any error
                transferResult.Check();

                // Print results
                foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
                {
                    Global.retorno = ("Upload efetuado com sucesso:" + transfer.FileName);
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Global.retorno = ("Erro: " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sim, sem dúvida será relevante Cleber! Depois você pode aceitar sua própria resposta para a sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Você já tentou usar o [FtpWebRequest](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) dessa forma?

```
FtpWebRequest requestFTP = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlFTP);
requestFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(usuario, senha);
requestFTP.EnableSsl = true;
```